# How to send multiple quantities in clickfunnel

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, shopify, payment-gateway

We have 4 to 5 pages in clickfunnel. In which first page is our main product page with variations. User will select any product variation, fill the form with his card details and submits the form.

Then there are 3-4 OTO pages, in which users needs to selects on any one button. And each button will have different quantities. So how we can pass multiple quantities of the same product. We are sending this info to shopify. And we have used stripe payment gateway.

For changes in the product_id we are using `data-purchase` attribute of that button. `data-purchase` will contain following details

```
{"product_id":"35***", "stripe_customer_id":"cus_*****"}
```

We want to pass multiple quantities of same product and it should reflect in **sales** tab **clickfunnel** [Clickfunnel Sales Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRBqP.png)

If there is only custom code integration option then if possible someone wants to share that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have the buyer choose multiple quantity of the same item, example: I am selling a Book, and I want to allow them to purchase '3x' that are all shipping to the same address, you can use this code to solve the above problem (only with Stripe payment):

Video on how to: https://youtu.be/3-E5-nV6AB4

```js
<script>
$(function(){
    $('[data-title*="oto-qty-select"] select').attr("data-storage", "false");
    $('[data-title*="oto-qty-select"] select').on("change", function(){
        var otoQtyProdId = parseInt($(this).val());
        //console.log(otoQtyProdId);
        otoSetQty(otoQtyProdId);            
    });
    function otoSetQty(prodId){
        $('[href*="#yes-link"]').each(function () {
            var selectedProd = $(this).data('purchase');
            selectedProd.product_id = prodId;
            $(this).data('purchase',selectedProd);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```